Bone won't show up in vertex group
I recently followed this tutorial series and I am currently rigging using rigify. When I got to the tongue rigging part with automatic weight paint my tongue was influenced by other bones around it. I have tried to fix this by manually removing the weight through the vertex group but some bones aren't showing up. I have tried to add the bone to the vertex group but it still didn't work. I've read somewhere that some bones need first to be deformed in the bone property tab, I tried that and it still didn't work. I try to only automatically weight paint the tongue and the bone I want by only selecting them when parenting and somehow other bones still influence the tongue. This has been driven me crazy the past few days now please help.
Also, how do I share files on this site?

You can share your Blend file via https://blend-exchange.com/ following the instructions there to copy the link on that page. Then edit your question here and paste the link into it. Your Blend file must be under 30 Meg in size for that site so remove any unnecessary objects first if it's larger.
